# Angular default option selected attribute not working as expected

Tags: angular

I would like to select the first option from the dropdown list. However, when I set `[attr.selected]="index == 1"` or `[attr.selected]="index == 0"` its not working but if I change the index value condition to `[attr.selected]="index == 2"`, it works. Although the index starting from 0 to 2 is present.

```
<select formControlName="segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1">
  <option [attr.selected]="index == 1" *ngFor="let segment of segmentations; let index=index;" [ngValue]="index">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Below is the segmentations array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name 1",
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        ...
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "name": "name 2",
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        ...
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "name": "name 3",
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 2,
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: post the `segmentations` array

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka. I've posted the the `segmentations` array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like this :

```
<select formControlName="segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1"> 
    <option *ngFor="let segment of segmentations; let i = index" [attr.value]="i" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Changing `[ngValue]` to `[attr.value]` and changing `[attr.selected]="index == 1"` to `[attr.selected]="index == 1 ? true : null"` fixed the issue.

Comment: `[attr.selected]="index == 1 ? true : null"` did it for me

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operation to return true or null values. otherwise, it will not be removed .

```
[attr.selected]="index == 1 ? true : null"
```

Comment: I tried this but it selects none of the option. So the dropdown appears empty.

Comment: Try to add ngModel value

Answer (score 1):

Use `[attr.selected] = "(index == 1)? 'any value whatsoever' : null"`

Html doesn't see the value of the selected attribute. It only sees if it is present or not. Angular removes the attribute if its value is null.

Comment: I tried this but it selects none of the option. So the dropdown appears empty.

Answer (score 0):

`<select formControlName="segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1" [(ngModel)]="1">`

This should work if the null value for selected attribute is failing.

Comment: It's giving me this error: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 2 in [1=$event] in ng:///AppModule/RequestDetailComponent.html@419:146 (""segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="1">`

Comment: Make it `[ngModel]=1` remove the ( )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `[attr.value]` and not `[ngvalue]`

Then use it like this as suggested in the first answer

```
<select formControlName="segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1"> 
<option *ngFor="let segment of segmentations; let i = index" [attr.value]="i" 
[attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>
```